# Bipartite matchings in multi-graphs

Tags: algorithm, variable-assignment

I am trying to find literature for a combinatorial optimization problem, in order to prove the NP-hardness (?) of another problem by reduction. The problem could be defined as a maximum weighted matching (assignment) problem in a k-regular complete balanced weighted bipartite multi-graph with integer weights. I know that it can be reduced to a known problem but I can't find a solution. I would appreciate it if someone gave me a hint.

Comment: Can you collapse the multi-edges by taking the max (since you can only use one in a matching anyway) and apply the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)?

Comment: This question might possibly be better suited to cs.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com (which doesn't mean that I think it doesn't belong here).

Comment: I am a little lost between "k-regular" and "complete". Can you give a simple example of such a graph.